# Python code for mutation operator in local search heuristics

Tags: python-2.7

Let a schedule as a permutation or arbitrary ordering of the requested tasks to perform.

Following is an example of **mutation operator:** to create neighbors of present schedule.

**Random swap:** Two permutation locations are chosen at random and the requested tasks are swapped, with 1-15 swaps (chosen at random) per mutation.

I do not understand how to code of the above mutation operator in Python 2.7. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What is the data structure of your chromosome/solution?

Comment: 1-D Array or list.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy you can choose two exclusive indices to swap, repeat this X time where X is uniform between 1 to 15. Here is some sample code:

```
import numpy as np
# chrom is list with genes
number_genes = len(chrom)
for i in range(np.random.choice(range(15), 1)[0]):
    ## Two exclusive indices, False for replacement so they are exclusive
    x1, x2 = np.random.choice(range(number_genes), 2, False)
    ## Swap the genes at the indices
    chrom[x1], chrom[x2] = chrom[x2], chrom[x1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan van der Vegt.

Comment: No problem, could you accept and upvote my answer if it solved your problem?